# Reading a file line by line and storing as an integer variable C++

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in c++. I am trying to read a file and want to save it as an integer variable. In my file I have.

```
4
3
1
```

Now I want the variables to have the following values

```
fu_unit_adder=4                                                                         
fu_unit_mult=3
fu_unit_div=1
```

what should I do??

my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int  fu_unit_adder;
    int  fu_unit_mult;
    int  fu_unit_div;

    ifstream config_file ("config.txt");
    if (config_file.is_open())
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            getline(config_file,fu_unit[j]);
            cout << fu_unit[j] << endl;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since you are a beginner, I highly recommend that you search the web and Stack Overflow before posting.  Issues regarding reading from a file have already been answered here many times.  You are "Parsing" or "Lexing".  Search using those terms too.

Answer (score 4):

If you know your file is going to be in that format, you might as well just use `>>` to extract from the file. You could do it as simply as this:

```
ifstream config_file ("config.txt");
config_file >> fu_unit_adder >> fu_unit_mult >> fu_unit_div;
```

If instead you want an array of units `fu_unit` that you might extend at some point, then you could do it like this:

```
ifstream config_file ("config.txt");
int fu_unit[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  config_file >> fu_unit[i];
}
```

If you want it a little more robust, you could check if the extractions are successful like so:

```
ifstream config_file ("config.txt");
int fu_unit[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  if (!(config_file >> fu_unit[i])) {
    // Extraction i failed, make sure you do config_file.clear() to continue
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried with this it is printing value but with some garbage values :                                                            int fu_unit[3],fu_adder,fu_mult,fu_div;
ifstream config_file ("config.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  config_file >> fu_unit[i];
  fu_adder=fu_unit[0];
  fu_mult=fu_unit[1];
  fu_div=fu_unit[2];
  cout<<fu_adder<<endl;
  cout<<fu_mult<<endl;
  cout<<fu_div<<endl;
}                                                                   outputs: 4 3 1 48589999

Comment: @user2319906 Simply because that is wrong. In the first iterator of your `for` loop, you only fill `fu_unit[0]` with a value. Then you try to put `fu_unit` elements `0`, `1`, and `2` into `fu_adder`, `fu_mult`, and `fu_div` respectively, But you haven't yet filled elements `1` and `2`! You seem to have no reason to use an array anyway. Use the first example I gave.

Comment: Hey Thanks. It tried with your first example and it worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the order of the data in the file is fixed and the count is 3 always, you may try:

```
getline(config_file,fu_unit_adder);
getline(config_file,fu_unit_mult);
getline(config_file,fu_unit_div);
```

There is no use to add a loop for only 3 variables. 3 statements would just be fine (if this is the case).

Comment: int fu_adder,fu_mult,fu_div;
ifstream config_file ("config.txt");
getline(config_file,fu_adder);
getline(config_file,fu_mult);
getline(config_file,fu_div);


system("pause");
    return 0;                                                                    getting error for getline, no argument is matches with getline.

Comment: @user2319906, this is based on the code pasted by you, I have not run or tested this code. I hope it will work:
`#include stuff...

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int  fu_unit_adder;
    int  fu_unit_mult;
    int  fu_unit_div;

    ifstream config_file ("config.txt");
    if (config_file.is_open())
    {
        getline(config_file,fu_unit_adder);
        cout << fu_unit_adder << endl;
        getline(config_file,fu_unit_mult);
        cout << fu_unit_mult << endl;
        getline(config_file,fu_unit_div);
        cout << fu_unit_div << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}`

Comment: Your suggestion reads the data into 3 *string* variables.  The text still has to be converted into integers.  This may be overkill for a beginner.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, I just wanted to convey that we don't need a loop to read 3 values. I used the code used in the question to explain.

Answer (score 1):

```
config_file.seekg(0,config_file.beg);
config_file >> fu_unit_adder;
config_file >> fu_unit_mult;
config_file >> fu_unit_div;
```

This should work for reading the first three variables.